# Cling UPnP replacement

Tags: android, upnp, cling

I have an Android app that uses the Cling/UPnP package. Unfortunately, that package is not longer maintained and has dependencies on ancient versions of other software.

Q: Is there an alternative? I've searched for a LONG time and haven't found any candidates.

Comment: [ohNet](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet) is a UPnP stack with Android API (note that public APIs aside, most of the code is in C/C++ )

Comment: I've gone the "nuclear option" and have written my own using sockets and lots of packet tracing